# How to set dynamic value in environment variable in dockerfile using shell script

Tags: shell, docker, environment-variables, dockerfile

My scenario is as follow

- I need to add "project" folder to docker container for production build but for development build I want to mount local volume to project folder of  container 
  eg. `ADD project /var/www/html/project` in production
   Nothing in development (I can copy a dummy folder in development)

  If  I copy whole project folder to container in development then any changes in project folder will invalidate the docker cache of layers after the add command. It will take time to build docker image in development.
- I want to use same docker file for both environment
- To achieve that I used `ADD $PROJECT_DIR /var/www/html/project` in docker file, where $PROJECT_DIR is environment variable
- Setting the environment variable in docker file like `ENV PROJECT_DIR project` or `ENV CONFIG_FILE_PATH dummy-folder` adds correct folders to container, but it needs me to change docker file each time.
- I can also pass "build-arg" parameter when building docker image like

  ```
  docker build -t myproject --build-arg "BUILD_TYPE=PROD" --build-arg "PROJECT_DIR=project" .
  ```

  As variables BUILD_TYPE and PROJECT_DIR are related, I want to set CONFIG_FILE_PATH variable based on BUILD_TYPE. This will prevent case of me forgetting to change one parameter.
- For setting the PROJECT_DIR variable I written following script "set_config_path.sh"

  ```
  if [ $BUILD_TYPE="PROD" ]; then 
      PROJECT_DIR="project";
  else 
      PROJECT_DIR="dummy-folder";
  fi
  ```
- I then run the script in dockerfile using

  ```
  RUN . /root/set_project_folder.sh
  ```

  Doing this, set_project_folder.sh script can access BUILD_TYPE variable but PROJECT_DIR is not reflected back in docker file
- When running the set_project_folder.sh in my local machine's terminal, the PROJECT_DIR variable is changed but it is not working with dockerfile

**Is there anyway we can change environment variable from subshell script e.g "set_config_path.sh" in above questions?**

If it is possible, It can be used in many use cases to make docker build dynamic

**Am I doing anything wrong here?

OR

Is there another good way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
FROM alpine
ARG BUILD_TYPE=prod
ARG CONFIG_FILE_PATH=config-$BUILD_TYPE.yml
RUN echo "BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE CONFIG_FILE_PATH=$CONFIG_FILE_PATH"
CMD echo "BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE CONFIG_FILE_PATH=$CONFIG_FILE_PATH"
```

The output would be like

```
Step 4/4 : RUN echo "BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE CONFIG_FILE_PATH=$CONFIG_FILE_PATH"
 ---> Running in b5de774d9ebe
BUILD_TYPE=prod CONFIG_FILE_PATH=config-prod.yml
```

But if you run the image

```
$ docker run 9df23a126bb1
BUILD_TYPE= CONFIG_FILE_PATH=
```

This is because build args are not persisted as environment variables. If you want to persists these variables in the image also then you need to add below

```
ENV BUILD_TYPE=$BUILD_TYPE CONFIG_FILE_PATH=$CONFIG_FILE_PATH
```

And now docker run will also output

```
$ docker run c250a9d1d109
BUILD_TYPE=prod CONFIG_FILE_PATH=config-prod.yml
```

Comment: Hi thanks, Your solution will work for the condition I put on the question, sorry I forgot to mentioned other conditions. I also want to use  "BUILD_TYPE" variable to copy some folders for production build but not for development build. I will update my question to include that also